# Why does "float" attribute change the size of the button in HTML?

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<body background="images/bg1.jpg" >
<header><h1>Sample</h1></header>
<br/><br/><br/>
<span class="button" >
    <a href="in.html" class="button" >
        In &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="icon"><img border="0" src="images/in.jpg"></span>
    </a>
</span>
<br/><br/>
<span class="button"> 
    <a href="out.html" class="button">
        Out <span class="icon"><img border="0" src="images/out.jpg"></span>
    </a>
</span>


</body>
```

CSS

```
.button {
float:left;
height:auto;
font-size:25px;
width:06em;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;
}

/*Button link styles*/
.button a:link, .button a:visited {
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
 color:#291919;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f34f23), to(#cf0014));
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration: none;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px #999;
text-shadow:2px 2px 0px #fe6c6c;
border-bottom:1px solid #78000c;
 margin: 0.2em;
 padding:0.2em;
 }
```

Now, if I change float attribute to "inherit" (header is center aligned), both the buttons come to center but their shape is not constant. Why is that? How can I make it constant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because floating implies `display: block`. By default, `<span>` is `display: inline`.

Comment: My requirement is make those 2 buttons center aligned without changing the button size(height and width). Can someone plz tell me how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the fact that the button is to be rendered as a block element. As said by DCoder, the `<span>` element renders as an inline element by default. You can force it into block mode:

```
display: block;
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/5beHU/)

Answer (score 0):

**Add to this** `clear : left` in your `.button`

**As like this**

```
.button {
clear:left;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/3UrWsCvy)***